# Scrollable PagerAdapter

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview, android-pageradapter

I did a `PagerAdapter`, and it works very well but when I put my phone horizontally, many things like `TextView` are not visible, because they are "below" the screen of the phone. I know I could put a `ScrollView`, but this option gives a lot of errors.

Is there another option besides the `ScrollView` or what does the error mean?

This is my code with the `LinearLayout` without any errors but the `PagerAdapter` isn't scrollable.

Java code:

```
public class SlideAdapter_info extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SlideAdapter_info(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object{
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_info, container, false);
        //other code to set the textviews and the imageview
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

`xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/slidelinear_info"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView /> ....

<!-- This allows me to have a circle shaped image-->
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slideimg"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
    app:civ_border_width="3dp" />

    <TextView /> ....

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the result: (horizontal)
[image]

This is the result:(vertical)
[image]

If instead of `LinearLayout` I put the `ScrollView`, `Android Studio` gives me this error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child`

`at esame.progetto.xhondar.github.com.info.SlideAdapter_info.instantiateItem(SlideAdapter_info.java:87)`

This is the row: 
`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_info, container, false);`

Comment: this is the grammar of how to put the image: "![](image)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child` is telling you exactly what your problem is. By just converting your `LinearLayout` to a `ScrollView`, you have multiple children. If you want your current layout to be scrollable within your `ViewPager`, you need to wrap your `LinearLayout` with the `ScrollView` in your layout xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/slidelinear_info"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical">
         <TextView /> ....
         <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView 
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/slideimg"
          android:layout_width="200dp"
          android:layout_height="200dp"
          android:paddingTop="10dp"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          app:civ_border_color="@color/black"
          app:civ_border_width="3dp" />
        <TextView /> ....
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: To expand on this, the containing `LinearLayou`t will be only one child, all its children are part of that view. `ScrollView` provides a wrapper for that contained single view to be scrollable within the layout space provided to `ScrollView`.

Comment: I had already tried this solution, but android give me this error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ScrollView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: You are casting your parent view to `LinearLayout` in `destroyItem()` and `isViewFromObject()`, so of course you are getting a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: That exception you copy/pasted explained that exactly. You need to look at the line causing the issue and see how your code was trying to make a `ScrollView` a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: You are right too xD, ok I've fixed the problem, now my PagerAdapter is scrollable